# I'm having trouble with Safari and CSS. How do I fix the issue without affecting Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I'm a beginner that just built a menu bar that changes the color of the webpage. It works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE. However, in Safari the 1st, 2nd, and 4th options are one pixel off when you hover over them. I was wondering how to fix this without messing up how the bar works in Chrome (because they both use Webkit right?).

This is the code for the webpage:
http://codepad.org/YrKz8Auy

And this is the code for the CSS:
http://codepad.org/pGnL5E5M

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a really complicated structure. Here's what your code could look like when simplified: http://jsfiddle.net/hCmrY/2/

Let me know if there are any Safari issues with it.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out! The bar works wonderfully across all browsers. Unfortunately I'm still an amateur when it comes to JavaScript, so I'm really gonna have to study up on it and jQuery. Is the JavaScript part saying (in layman's terms) that if one of the options is clicked that isn't "Home", it will take the background property, replace the value with the "[color]" in "bg-[color]"? Then if you click "Home" it will add back in the "default-bg" class that makes it normal again?

Comment: @Lolobear If you want to thank "so much", make sure to accept *and* upvote the answer.

Comment: @BlaXpirit I tried but it says I need 15 reputation. Right now I'm at 13 so as soon as I get there, I'll definitely upvote.

Comment: @Lolobear: you're correct in your description of the conditional. Good luck with your future projects :)